# Spring / Hibernate: how to get Configuration from LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'd like to run `Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList()`. However Hibernate is configured using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. How do I get to the `Configuration` object from a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instance? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to run `Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList()`?

Comment: Obviously because I want to get Hibernate's idea of how to update the schema to match the entities, but do something else with it rather than just apply it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this was a two-days wall vs. head marathon, but in the end I found a solution, although it's somewhat hacky.

I cam across Hibernate's [`Integrator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator.html), which is scarcely mentioned in the docs. Some more information about it can be found in the linked Hibernate JIRA issues [HHH-5562](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5562) and [HHH-6081](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6081). However, one can piece together enough information for a working example from [a few sources](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=hibernate%20Integrator#q=hibernate%20Integrator) once you know the keyword. Still it does not play well with Spring, a problem mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019820/using-hibernate-4s-integrator-pattern-and-springs-dependency-injection).

So, the final solution was a bit hackish, but it works:

```
public class GetConfigIntegrator implements Integrator {

    private static Configuration configuration;

    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public void integrate(Configuration configuration, /* ... */) {
        GetConfigIntegrator.configuration = configuration;
    }

    // Empty Integrator implementation...
}
```

As can be seen, this silly integrator simply stores the configuration in a static variable, so it can be accessed later. Not ideal, but faced with no options one rejoices finding such a path.

To register the integrator, the following file needs to be created, with one line per integrator class (full name), like so:

```
# src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator:
<full package name>.GetConfigIntegrator
```