# Entity listeners at repository level - how to also affect cascated entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, cascade

I've added a listener layer to my project by overriding the **SimpleJpaRepository**, so it looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public <S extends E> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        persister.beforeCreateListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        persister.afterCreateListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        S merged;
        persister.beforeUpdateListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
        merged = entityManager.merge(entity);
        persister.afterUpdateListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
        return merged;
    }
}

@Override
public void delete(E entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");
    if (entity instanceof LogicRemovable) {
        ((LogicRemovable) entity).setLogicRemoved(true);
        save(entity);
    } else {
        persister.beforeDeleteListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(entity) ? entity : entityManager.merge(entity));
        persister.afterDeleteListenersFor(entity.getClass()).execute(entity);
    }
}
```

Where **persister** is an interface that provides the listeners for the given class and for the given type (BEFORE_CREATE, AFTER_CREATE etc) in runtime, injecting everything the listener needs.

Everything works amazing, and all I have to do is annotate the listener whith a given annotation.

Problem is: since this layer is on repository level, it is not affecting cascated entities.

So, how can I make it also affect cascated entities?

For me, the perfect solution would be 'just move the layer from repository to X (like entity manager, not sure) and it'll affect both', but I have no idea what that X is.

Or maybe there are another solutions, any are welcome.

Thanks!

-glauber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered once a similiar question here.

[Using Hibernate 4's Integrator pattern and Spring's dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019820/using-hibernate-4s-integrator-pattern-and-springs-dependency-injection/16045272#16045272)

With this you can use spring beans as hibernate listeners, which are on the lowest level. Each entity which is flushed will trigger the listener.

It depends what you are using you listeners for. HibernateListeners are not supposed to modify or create new entities as the `ActionQueue` is already built. (But `Envers` however is using these listeners to create the revision history.)

Comment: Hey Martin, interesting answer. I'm not sure it covers what I need, will have to figure out, but still looks like a nice solution.

I'm using the listeners to whatever needs to happen when an entity is modified, be it create or remove dependencies, modify another entity that is related to the modified entity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with listeners?  Are you using an entity listener?  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html.  Can you create an entity listener and annotate a base entity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the solution Martin Frey, I was able to adapt my solution using yours.

What I did was to create only six generic Hibernate Listeners, one for each event type I was using, just like your solution. But then I moved those lines that were in the repository into each corresponding hibernate listener, so there is no change in usability.

The other things I needed to take care of:

1) had to do  an entity check before calling the listeners, due to auditing (an audited entity creates its own table, and it  does go through the listeners, but since it doesn't have its own java type, it comes as a map. So I was getting a ClassCastException.

2) I have to update the state dynamically. Not going much into details, but this is what I'm talking about: [PreInsertEventListener object modifications not sticky](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=940610&start=0)

Since my listeners were generic, I couldn't just hardcode the new values, so I went through how Hibernate was creating the state array and recreated and overrode it.

The final code now looks like this:

```
@Component
public class HibernatePreInsertEventListener<T extends Entity> implements HibernateEventListener, PreInsertEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private Persister persister;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        Object someEntity = event.getEntity();
        if(Entity.class.isAssignableFrom(someEntity.getClass())) {
            T entity = (T) someEntity;
            Class<T> entityClass = (Class<T>) entity.getClass();

            persister.beforeCreateListenersFor(entityClass).execute(entity);
            updateState(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void updateState(PreInsertEvent event) {
        Object[] newState = event.getPersister().getPropertyValuesToInsert(event.getEntity(), null, event.getSession());

        for (int i = 0; i < newState.length; i++) {
            Object o = newState[i];
            event.getState()[i] = o;
        }
    }
}
```